# MS Access Input Masks and Search Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, user-input, ms-access-2016

Thanks for reading.

TLDR; Is there a way to search a cell in a table that has an input mask without including the symbols in that input mask? (specifically a Phone number with an input mask `!\(999") "000\-0000;0;_` )

The issue I'm running into is that I have a table with a bunch of customer phone numbers and I would like to keep these numbers stored with an input mask, making the Area Code more visible. However, when I run a search query on said phone numbers, due to the input mask, it is proving very difficult to have consistent results. Is there a way to just search the numbers stored and not the symbols sored in the cell? The current way I'm filtering the results is using the following in the Criteria segment of my query.

`Like IIf(IsNull([ClientList]![Cell]),"*",IIf(IsNull([Forms]![ClientInquiry]![PhnNumberTB]),"*",[Forms]![ClientInquiry]![PhnNumberTB] & "*"))`

*Where PhnNumberTB is a textbox on the search form and Cell is the Cellphone number stored in the table.*

I am also VERY new to Access and SQL so if there is a way around searching with this method any tips would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Store phone numbers without format, and do formatting when displaying them, will reduce a lot of problems.

Comment: @Luuk Ok got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a combo box and choose option to find a record on my form based on value i selected.

Also when designing the input mask of the telephone number, choose to store the numbers without the input mask.

Attached are images that shows the steps and search form/results

I didn't try the option not to store the numbers without input mask, so i can't advice on that.
[image: combo box step i]

[image: combo box step 2]

[image: phone input mask storage option at table design]

[image: Search functionality at work]